# Why I got Instance of Future<List<int>> while trying to display data with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, instance, future

I'm trying to display value of Future<List> with flutter in a text of an alert dialog but I got instance of future<list>.
this is my code :

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text(
                            'Be Careful ${characteristic46?.read()}'),
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(45, 231, 148, 54),
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      );
                    });
              });
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `((timeStamp) async{ final data  = await characteristic46?.read(); await showDialog()` and use `data` instead of calling the method

Answer (score 1):

Your `characteristic46?.read()` is `Future` and you need to `await` for its result. Try this:

```
Future<void> showFutureDialog(BluetoothCharacteristic? characteristic46) async{
    var result = await characteristic46?.read();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp){
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text(
                        'Be Careful $result'),
                    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(45, 231, 148, 54),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  );
                });
          });
}
```

then call `showFutureDialog` inside `initState`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    showFutureDialog(characteristic46);
  }
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249804/discussion-between-rania-and-eamirho3ein).